# Is there any way to improve the application load time in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

The initial application load time of an angular application for e2e testing using Protractor is consuming a longer time. Is there any way to improve this?

The page object used for initial login is :

```
var Login = function() {
var username = element(by.model('login.username'));
var pass = element(by.model('login.userpwd'));
var loginButton = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="logindiv"]/div[3]/button'));

this.login = function(name, password) {
     browser.get(config.loginUrl);
     username.sendKeys(name);
     pass.sendKeys(password);
     loginButton.click();
  };
};
module.exports = Login;
```

---

Comment: Do you have some heavy initialization outside of your `it` and `beforeEach` blocks? If so, do not replicate it across the tests, but use `onPrepare` for that so that it would get executed only once. A sample of your tests might help a bit in determining what slows them down for you...

Comment: There is no heavy initialization outside of  `it` and `beforeEach`. The sample for login is :                                                                                               `var LoginPage = require('./login.page.po.js');
describe('Login', function() {
 var page;
 
 beforeEach(function() {
   page = new LoginPage();
 });

  it('should login and go to home', function() {
  page.login(userName,password);
  expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("/home");
  });`

Comment: what's the content of `login.page.po.js`?

Comment: I have edited the code inline